# How to group results of a query by 'less than equal to' grouping?

Tags: mysql

I need to have the count of all items with a specific status <= a particular day. So if I group by 'day' then all the 'open' items till that day must be counted. So for the next 'day' it'd be a cumulative sum including the 'open' items from the previous day(s).

Here's an example of the schema:

[image]

**Query**: How many items were in a specific status on a particular day?

**Expected output:**

```
    day*| status | count
    ---------------------
     1  |  open  |  3
     2  |  open  |  6 //3 today and 3 from the previous day
     2  |  maybe |  1
     2  |  agree |  2
     2  |  open  |  6 //nothing new was 'open'
     3  |  open  |  8 //2 new
     3  |  agree |  4 //2 new

*could also be date or some other format. Not a rule, but just for illustration
```

I'm quite stumped with how to formulate this. I'm sure you need a self (inner) join but I don't know on what to do the group-by and what exactly to count since it's a cumulative sum. I'm guessing I'd need some temporary variables and the like but not sure how to do this in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You might try using WITH ROLLUP after your GROUP BY.
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

Comment: Good point. But `With Rollup` seems to roll up only the 'outer group' of day and not by inner group of statuses. So I get the total count of items per day and not cumulative count for each status as in the question

Comment: Interesting thing about roll up is that it does group by - 1. So you can "trick" it by adding another group by item which could be the same data field as one already specified: day as day, day as day1 ... group by day, day1 with rollup